# __lt__ для Python как писать в тексте ответа?

Tags: поддержка, markdown

Два подчеркивания с обеих сторон превращают текст в жирный. Вот так: **lt**
А если добавить 4 подчеркивания с каждой стороны - получается по 4 подчеркивания....  Вот так: ____lt____

Как писать "магический методы" Python с двумя подчеркиваниями с каждой стороны?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Нужно выделить эту часть как код: `__it__`

```
`__it__`
```

Либо добавить отступ 4 пробела, для оформления блока кода:

```
    __it__
```

Кроме того можно воспользоваться возможностью экранировать символы с помощью обратного слэша: __it__

```
\__it__
```